# not able to convert json to csv

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

finding difficult to convert json to csv using jq command

```
{
  "ResourceTagMappingList": [
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:027906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e404f4440d",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "useast-prod-vpn01-cisco",
          "Key": "Name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:017906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a447508555e",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "useast-prod-vpn02-cisco",
          "Key": "Name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:5079063766562328:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a44754408e"
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:07945406375465228:image/ami-012446b78ea15546fbd",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "processor-USE-img-18022019",
          "Key": "Name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079063765434343228:image/ami-0624f58fdf53eacd3775",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "DevOpsUSE1",
          "Key": "AppCluster"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Image",
          "Key": "AppEnv"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Image",
          "Key": "AppGroup"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079063765228:instance/i-0087f44110c478d49",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "Inst01USE1",
          "Key": "App01"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Production",
          "Key": "AppEnv"
        },
        {
          "Value": "usev-app01-ond-asg01",
          "Key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName"
        },
        {
          "Value": "lt-0ec354ad560e508cc",
          "Key": "aws:ec2launchtemplate:id"
        },
        {
          "Value": "8",
          "Key": "aws:ec2launchtemplate:version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

output expecting to get :

```
"ResourceARN","Name","AppCluster","AppEnv","AppGroup","App01","aws:autoscaling:groupName","aws:ec2launchtemplate:id","aws:ec2launchtemplate:version"
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:027906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e404f4440d","useast-prod-vpn01-cisco",null,null,null,null,null,null,null
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:017906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a447508555e","useast-prod-vpn02-cisco",null,null,null,null,null,null,null
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:5079063766562328:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a44754408e",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:07945406375465228:image/ami-012446b78ea15546fbd","processor-USE-img-18022019",null,null,null,null,null,null,null
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079063765434343228:image/ami-0624f58fdf53eacd3775",null,"DevOpsUSE1","Image","Image",null,null,null,null
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079550666376445228:instance/i-0087f44110c478d49",null,null,"Production",null,"Inst01USE1","usev-app01-ond-asg01","lt-0ec354ad560e508cc","8"
```

Something I tried, but didn't able achieve:

```
cat resourcesfile.json | jq -rc '.ResourceTagMappingList[]|{ResourceARN,tags: [ .["Tags"][]["Value"] ]}|.[]'
cat resourcesfile.json | jq -r '[[.ResourceTagMappingList[]|[{ResourceARN},(.Tags|from_entries)]|add]|.[]|to_entries|.[]|.key]|unique' 
cat resourcesfile.json | jq -r '[.ResourceTagMappingList[]|[[{ResourceARN},(.Tags|from_entries)]|add]|.[]|to_entries|.[]|.key]|unique as $fields | ($fields | @csv)'
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '
reduce .ResourceTagMappingList[] as $p
( { names: null, rows: null };
  ( $p | { ResourceARN } + ( .Tags // [] | from_entries ) ) as $p
  | .names[$p | keys_unsorted[]] = 0
  | .rows += [$p]
) | ( .names | keys_unsorted ) as $names
| $names, ( .rows[] | [.[$names[]]] )
| @csv' file
"ResourceARN","Name","AppCluster","AppEnv","AppGroup","App01","aws:autoscaling:groupName","aws:ec2launchtemplate:id","aws:ec2launchtemplate:version"
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:027906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e404f4440d","useast-prod-vpn01-cisco",,,,,,,
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:017906322765228:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a447508555e","useast-prod-vpn02-cisco",,,,,,,
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:5079063766562328:customer-gateway/cgw-e7a44754408e",,,,,,,,
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:07945406375465228:image/ami-012446b78ea15546fbd","processor-USE-img-18022019",,,,,,,
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079063765434343228:image/ami-0624f58fdf53eacd3775",,"DevOpsUSE1","Image","Image",,,,
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:079063765228:instance/i-0087f44110c478d49",,,"Production",,"Inst01USE1","usev-app01-ond-asg01","lt-0ec354ad560e508cc","8"
```

Comment: Thanks oguz ismail for your help!!!... but tag names are not constant and I have many objects having different tag key names....can you please help to make this to consider dynamically

Comment: Great!!!..thanks again...one more point, first rows needs to have key names as a column header

Comment: Oguz ismail@ It's perfect and awesome... I am grateful for your help